# Open multiple text files from multiple servers ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all apologize for my bad English.

At work we have an Intranet, we developed an application in Asp.NET which is replicated on 4 servers, we have a computer acting as a balancer that redirects clients to a specific server.

By permissions I have only access to the balancer and not the server where the page is published.

The application has automated processes that creates a text file on each of the servers. In the path `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ExportaPDF.`

If I enter the following path from a browser `10.48.203.1/ExportaPDF/Consulta_06102014.txt` (considering that the IP belongs to the balancer) shows me the content of the text file, but I can not control what server I am accessing.

I need to create a page in ASP.NET that is replicated on each server which shows me the content of the 4 servers. I mean you see the contents of text files:

```
10.48.203.2/ExportaPDF/Consulta_06102014.txt

10.48.203.3/ExportaPDF/Consulta_06102014.txt

10.48.203.4/ExportaPDF/Consulta_06102014.txt

10.48.203.5/ExportaPDF/Consulta_06102014.txt
```

As he had already said the problem is that it only has access to the balancer (10.48.203.1) and I wonder if there is any way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You might get lucky with multiple calls until u get all the files LOL.

Comment: You should not design the app around ability to access physical files on specific servers. It should be central location, something like a database

Comment: why would it matter which server you are accessing? the point on a load balancer is just that... and to of course, ease traffic across all the servers.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a page in ASP.NET that is replicated on each server
>   which shows me the content of the 4 servers.

**Option 1:**
You can add functionality to the servers to fetch those files as the servers are behind the load balancer and can have direct access to all the other servers. You might be able to add a button in the admin page to ZIP all files and put it in a shared location. In this scenario, it doesn't matter which server your call hits.

**Option 2:**
Having all servers using the same file. You might get some concurrency issues. Using a flat file to store data is not the best option for production. I would recommended using a database

**Option 3:**
Configure rules on the balancer to accommodate your requirement.

**Option 4:**
You can automate the process by sending periodic email from the servers with the files

**Option 5:**
Add a new project to your solution with simple HTTP endpoint. For example, you can use WebApi endpoint to fetch the data. The end point will be bound to a specific URL so the balancer will no be an issue.

So many options. We need more info to narrow it down...
You might want to examine those and other options looking at the: time to implement, robustness, security (even if it's on the intranet, it might be a security concern that everyone on the LAN can access those files), future extensibility etc.